# set properties of object stored in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of image objects:

```
var pics = ["pic1","pic2","pic3","pic4","pic5","pic6"]
```

I want to loop through and set the style.left value to 10 less than the current value.  I tried:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
pics[i].style.left=pics[i].style.left-10
}
```

but this does not seem to work.  What do I need to do?

Comment: Are the images references to actual DOM elements?

Comment: That is an array of strings

Comment: Once we get past the array of string/array of image object issue, can you clarify "does not seem to work" - in what way?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I think the strings are the issue here. There might be another problem with the code OP wrote for sure, but he/she doesn't know that yet because of the string issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of thinking to solve it using javascript, you can actually solve it using css. Just apply a common class to those image elements and appply the following style:

```
.myImg{
     margin-left: -10px;
}
```

**OR**

```
.myImg{
     transform: translate(-10px, 0px);
}
```

This will move the image `10px` backward from the already applied `left` css property. (*I hope you are trying to do the same using javascript i.e subtracting `-10`*).

Comment: This looks great.  I used this in conjunction with the answer above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of strings, not an array of elements. If those are ID's, you could use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to turn a string ID into an element:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
    var image = document.getElementById(pics[i]);
    image.style.left=image.style.left-10
}
```

Also, you can improve your code by a bit, consider:

```
// Use pics.length instead of hardcoding the array length here.
// This way if you add/remove element later, you won't need to
// update this loop.
for (i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) { 
    var image = document.getElementById(pics[i]);
    image.style.left=image.style.left-10
}
```

---

As a sidenote, you need to also remember that this code should be executed [only after DOM is available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) otherwise `getElementById()` will return null.

Comment: and why don't to put the loop till  to the end of the array's element please update in answer

Comment: `image.style.left` comes with unit. You should remove that unit to do calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The `left` property inside the style object in only available for DOM nodes.

In the example you provided, you just have an array of strings, but even if it was image objects it wouldn't work. You can create the DOM nodes like this:

```
var image = document.createElement("img")
image.style.left = "10px"
```

But make sure to always try to fix visual issues with CSS instead of JavaScript.